# Basic photo effects functions for Java

Tags: java, photo, effects

I've started to translate my app from Delphi to Java and app contains lots of function that handle image editing, such as Levels, Curves, Hue/Saturation, various Blending etc. Basically effects that Photoshop contains.

Is there some good library with these functions, free of paid, doesn't matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try OpenCV for Java: http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html

I've used the C++ version a LOT, and it is really useful indeed.